# I don't want to move header with VerticalFieldManager, how?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

This is my coding, I don't want header to move as i scrolldown the main1, how to do that?

```
   VerticalFieldManager main1 =
       new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
   XmlDataManager xmlData = new XmlDataManager();
   BitmapField header = 
       xmlData.getImageFromUrl("http://wiztech.pk/ali/eve/"+bannerData.catg);  
   main1.add(header);
```

Comment: can u give me answer except just editing code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add header to MainScreen, not to VerticalFieldManager.

Just use `add(header)`

Comment: Do you create MainScreen(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL) ?

Comment: public class DetailScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{ i have don't like this

Comment: @redline I think you mean setTitle() or setBanner() on MainScreen.

Comment: Michael Donohue is right. Add your header field to `MainScreen` via `MainScreen.setTitle(Field title)` or `MainScreen.setStatus(Field status)`.

Comment: @Michael Donohue, Ya, I want to setBanner on main screen.

Comment: @Michael, I did super.setTitle(header);